# Trigger apache authentication depending on URL parameter

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, locationmatch

I need to trigger the apache authentications depending only on a URL parameter. For instance, The following URL http://mySillyApplication.com/items/browse?collection=9&sort_field=Title&num_items=10&... I need to trigger the authentication only if collection=9 . I've tried many things but I couldn't find how to do it. I think the key is to find a RewriteRule that could activate the LocationMatch .... just a guess:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*(?:^|&))collection=9((?:&|$).*) [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) - [R=401]
   <LocationMatch "....don't know...">
           AuthType Basic
           AuthName "Login Required"
           AuthUserFile /var/www/.../.htpwd
           Require valid-user
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
           Satisfy any
   </LocationMatch>
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is nothing typically on the level of the http server. I suggest you implement your authentication / authorization logic in some scripting framework and forward the task there. That offers _much_ more flexibility.

Comment: Yeah...well... let's say the URL I'm trying to modify it's from an old CMS that I prefer not to modify in any way.

Comment: Then implement a trivial proxy script wrapping that legacy logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<If> Directive` if Apache is 2.4.26 and later http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if

So, try the following code :

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /(collection=9&)/">

       AuthType Basic
       AuthName "Login Required"
       AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
       Require valid-user
       Order allow,deny
       Deny from all
       Satisfy any
</If>
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammed but my apache version is Apache v.2.2.22 . I'll try to upgrade but I'm not sure if it is possible due to dependencies.